# How to translate "If everything goes as planned..."

Tags: translation, chengyu

For example

> If everything goes as planned, we should have a successful journey.
>
> I hope everything goes as planned tonight.

1. Specifically, I'm wondering if there's an idiom for this. If not, what's a more eloquent way of saying this?
2. What's usually used colloquially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

假若一切顺利...

If everything goes according to plan (=smoothly)... E.g.:

希望今晚一切都顺利举行。
I hope everything goes as planned tonight.

Or of course you can apply a literal translation, like 希望今晚一切都按计划进行。
But I think 顺利 is better, native way to express this in Chinese.

Comment: Did you mean to say `假如`?

Comment: @tofu_bacon Perhaps, there are many ways to say "if" in Chinese, try one that fits your text.

Comment: Actually we don't usually use `假若` in Chinese. `假如` is more popular.

Answer (score 3):

If everything goes as planned.
 如果一切按计划进行.

In daily conversation, we use "如果一切顺利" more often.

(假若 is more often used in written language and is quite formal.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say (and commonly heard in Hong Kong) 如無意外.

It would be translated as "If there are no accident".

If everything goes as planned, there are no accident.

Answer (score 0):

“一帆风顺” this also a well known idioms that bless people to do things smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Another way to say it in Chinese: 不出意外的话,...

or, in an expression popular on internet:  不出啥么幺蛾子的话。。。